# Python Multiprocessing Queue thows WindowsError: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a directory with subdirectories of files, and am extracting information in the form of a pandas dataframe from the files in each subdirectory, then rejoining the pandas dataframes from each into one csv file using multiprocessing. I am using a queue to store the local dataframes returned by each process and append them to the file to avoid write conflicts. Here is my code:

```
def work(cmd, q):
    df_local = function_which_returns_dataframe(cmd)
    if not df_local.empty:
        q.put(df_local)
    else:
        print("Empty:", cmd)

def listener(file, q):
    while True:
        line = q.get()
        if isinstance(line, pd.DataFrame):
            line.to_csv(file, mode='a', header=False)
        elif line == 'kill':
            return

def main(args):    
    cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    patient_dirs = [os.path.join(args.input_dir, x) for x in os.listdir(args.input_dir)]
    threads = []
    file = os.path.join(args.output_dir, 'concepts_all_%s.csv' % identifier)

    #setup manager with write access to file
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()
    header_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['patient_id', 'lookup_id', 'begin_inx', 'end_inx', 'mention_type', 'codingScheme', 'code', 'preferredText', 'word_phrase'])
    header_df.loc[len(header_df)] = ['patient_id', 'lookup_id', 'begin_inx', 'end_inx', 'mention_type', 'codingScheme', 'code', 'preferredText', 'word_phrase']
    q.put(header_df)

    #start write process
    writer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=listener, args=(file, q))
    writer_process.start()

    # now spawn processes from each patient dir*
    while threads or patient_dirs:
        if (len(threads) < cpus) and patient_dirs:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=work, args=[patient_dirs.pop(), q])
            p.start()
            threads.append(p)
        else:
            for thread in threads:
                if not thread.is_alive():
                    threads.remove(thread)

    #finish write
    q.put('kill')
    writer_process.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('input_dir', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('output_dir', type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

This code works fine on a smaller testing directory, but I start receiving the following error message after running it on a larger directory for some time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "I:\sutter\multiproc_test.py", line 20, in work
    q.put(df_local)
  File "<string>", line 2, in put
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 755, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 742, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 167, in Client
    c = PipeClient(address)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 383, in PipeClient
    win32.WaitNamedPipe(address, 1000)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Is the queue limited in size or have I not setup my write out method properly? Could this have something to do with handling of the case where empty dataframes are returned?

Answer (score 0):

use [`dask`](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) instead, its has similar syntax to pandas only its parallel (essentially its lots of parallel pandas datafames) and lazy (this helps with avoiding ram limitations).

if the files you are extracting are for example of type `csv`, do this:

```
from dask.distributed import Client  
import dask.dataframe as dd

client = Client() #  ensures multiprocessing

ddf = dd.read_csv(r'sub\**\*.csv')  # reads all the csv files inside of the subdirectories of the subdirectories
```

if the files are of a different type and `pandas` can read them `dask` most likely can also [read](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html#api) them.

for `xml` it would look something like this:

```
import dask 
from glob import iglob

@dask.delayed  # this function will now run via the multiprocessing client 
def work(files_path):
    df_local = function_which_returns_dataframe(files_path)
    if not df_local.empty:
        return df_local 
    else:
        print("Empty:", files_path)

client = Client() #  ensures multiprocessing
files_paths = iglob(r'sub\**\*.xml') # an iterator of all the xml file paths

# read lazily all the xml files
delayed_objs = (work(files_path) for files_path in files_paths) 

ddf = dd.from_delayed(delayed_objs)  # combine to one dataframe
```

I suggest you read [this](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.from_delayed) and provide a `meta` to `from_delayed`

if you wish to turn `ddf` to a `pandas.DataFrame` simply do this:

```
df = ddf.compute()
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually have a custom function to extract from XML files into csv-like format, which is why I was using pandas.

Comment: then you you can use `glob` and `delayed` ill edit in the answer, do all those "csv-like format" `dataframe`'s have the same schema ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks-- haven't checked out glob yet. Do you have any insights into why the queue writer isn't working?